# libgdx how to set position of camera from another non-main class? [Java]

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, libgdx

I think it's very basic java question. I have two classes: Main and InputManager class:

```
public class InputManager implements InputProcessor {
    Main main = new Main();
    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        switch (keycode) {
            case Keys.A:
                System.out.println(main.cam.position.set(1, 0, 0));
                break;
        }
        return false;
    } // etc...
```

The Main class has public OrthographicCamera cam; field, I just want to set position of cam from InputManager class. How this can be done? Pressing "A" shows me "Nullpointer exception". Can't find any examples :(

Comment: Can you include your class `Main`? I am almost certain your issue is a Java issue not libgdx but I would need to see `Main` in order to confirm

Comment: https://pastebin.com/uZ3QaBER

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Main main = new Main();
```

According to your code `cam` of `Main` class is null because you're initialising camera inside `create()` method that is lifecycle method of [ApplicationListener](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/The-life-cycle#applicationlistener), called when the Application is first created..

Instead of constructing new Object use already created by this :

```
Main main=  (Main)Gdx.app.getApplicationListener();
```

Answer (score 0):

Either cam is null and or position is null.

Which ever is null will need to be set/initialised so that it is not null.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the documentation for ApplicationAdapter and make sure you're using it correctly.

For this particular problem it looks like the create() overload would provide the initialization for cam and position that is needed. You can call it right after initializing the object, or inside the constructor.